# Ошибка startForeground()

Tags: android, android-service

Решил написать приложение, которое присылает уведомление при определенном уровне заряда. Но проблема в том, что при закрытии приложения, сервис так же закрывается и уведомления не приходят:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

**BootReciever.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

}

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
private static final int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}



public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return Service.START_STICKY;

}

BroadcastReceiver mBatteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int chargeState = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        switch (chargeState) {
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:

                if(isCharging) {

                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this)
                     .setContentTitle("Charging...")
                     .setContentText("Battery level is: " + Integer.toString(level))
                     .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat);
                    final Notification notification = builder.build();

                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                    startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                }
                break;

            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:

                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:

                break;
        }

    }
};


public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver);

    stopSelf();
}
```

}

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи или подсказке.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно ваш mBatteryInfoReceiver сделать отдельным классом и прописать его в манифесте с экшеном ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED